# Adjusting cell values whenever a new row is added - maintain sort capabilities

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I work for an apparel company. We have image boards containing all seasonal designs, and a matching excel grid containing other useful information. Here is a small board with images:

[image: Board image]

The order of the board images is important, so I need to be able to sort my excel grid by the order of images. We assign order numbers left to right, top to bottom, just as someone would read a book. I've constructed my excel grid to look like the below:

[image: excel grid image]

To create the order, I wrote my formula as `A[row number 1 above] +1`. So cell `A2 = 1`, cell `A3 = 2`, cell `A4 = 3`, and so on.

This is all fine and dandy until we come across 2 situations:

#1 I have to sort the other columns. I sometimes need to sort column `F` "Forecast volume" by ascending. This obviously messes up the order in column `A`.

#2 I need to add a new style in as a new row, while still maintaining order in the grid that matches to the image. See below image. I want to add a burgundy color to slot in as item #5, while automatically adjusting adding 1 to the rest of the items below it.

[image: Board image added style]

[Here](https://app.box.com/s/s9f3ncgro6p5juxrmt6ppettxb0575c8) is my file for reference. Is there a solution that allows me to add and sort rows, while still being able to order my styles correctly, according to the provided images?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need that order column hard coded, and not formulas. If you want automation that will be through VBA/Office Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1
When you sort part of your list, do not include column A in sorting (do not select it).

Problem #2
In column A use a counter based on a formula:

```
=MAX(start:prev)+1
```

**start** and **prev** are names defined in the Name Manager.
**start** refers to the first cell in your counter (the cell containing 1), in your example $A$2. This is an absolute reference at least for row.
**prev** refers to the cell immediately above the active cell. This is a **relative** reference (without $). So, for example, if an active cell is A3, **prev** should refer to A2.
With this counter you can insert rows and you need only copy the formula to the new row. You can also remove rows without problems. Empty cells or cells with text are skipped.